# What causes the error NotebookEvaluate::nbnfnd?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, files-and-directories, kernel

Help says:

```
NotebookEvaluate can take either a NotebookObject or a filename referencing a notebook file.
```

therefore, I wonder why

```
SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[];
nbFile = "aNotebook.nb";
FileExistsQ[nbFile]
NotebookEvaluate[nbFile]
```

returns

```
Out[3]= True
During evaluation of In[1]:= NotebookEvaluate::nbnfnd: Unable to find the notebook aNotebook.nb. >>
Out[4]= $Failed
```

and, on the contrary,

```
SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[];
nbFile = FileNameJoin @  {Directory[], "aNotebook.nb"};
FileExistsQ[nbFile]
NotebookEvaluate[nbFile]
```

returns

```
True
```

It looks like `NotebookEvaluate` could not take relative paths; even worse, the notebook `aNotebook.nb` contains simply

```
f[x_]:=x+1;
```

but, even in the latter case, the function `f` remains undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that FrontEnd related functions do not respect Kernel related settings.

I do not understand why this is not uniform. It is not clearly stated (I have not found it) which functions are FE related. Of course, it is easy to guess but that is not what you expect, the more that there is an appropriate tutorial which should explain that: [NamingAndFindingFiles](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html).

Ok, enough whining, I am talking about functions like:

```
NotebookSave NotebookOpen NotebookEvaluate NotebookImport
```

and the directory search stack for them is given by `NotebookPath`. So this should do:

```
PrependTo[
   CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "NotebookPath"],
   NotebookDirectory[]
]

NotebookOpen[nbFile]
```

Comment: Huh. Why would one need the front end to `NotebookEvaluate`? What's the appropriate way to do what OP is doing (evaluating a notebook with a definition for `f`) without invoking front end functions?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP FrontEnd parses boxes and sends the result to the kernel. You can do this from the Kernel but by `UsingFrontEnd`.

Comment: Ah, of course, because notebooks are made of boxes, unlike packages with code cells. I was thinking of `Get`, but it obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for replies !! I' m sorry for the repeating, but I' m still incapable to understand how comes that FrontEnd is involved in commands that, evidently misunderstanding,  I thought to be kernel related only. Please, can you explain a bit further ?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else stumbles across this problem: a possible workaround is given by the function [AbsoluteFilename](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteFileName.html). Given a relative path it can construct the absolute one, which in return causes no problems for `NotebookEvaluate`.